# MySql - Reordering the rows of a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table (with no PK) that is being `inserted into` by an regular event. It is currently unordered, and I would like to order it in the fashion of

```
select * from t1 order by col1 ASC,col2 DESC
```

Constraints are as follows:

- For performance reasons I can't create a new temporary table to store the ordered data in
- For cleanness of the user-interface I must assume that all select statements will be without an order by clause
- Because of the insert into mechanism I can't order the table while it's being built up

Is there some way of doing this that I don't know about/have overlooked?

Comment: then why do you need it ordered?

Comment: I think you don't need to order your table but add index to you table instead

Comment: because I need the `select * from t1` statement to return an ordered table to the user (who isn't expected to know what to sort on [or how to do it])

Comment: can you create a view that the user selects from?

Comment: Yes I can; creating a view that is also on a scheduled event might work

Comment: A view, once defined, continues to stay defined, and when used refers back to the underlying tables. You don't need to DROP and CREATE the view each time the table is updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some way of doing this that I don't know about/have overlooked?

No. And [here is a very good explanation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql). Quoting the most revelant part:

> In the SQL world, order is not an inherent property of a set of data. Thus, you get no guarantees from your RDBMS that your data will come back in a certain order -- or even in a consistent order -- unless you query your data with an ORDER BY clause.

That being said, if you remove your performance requirements, you could create an ordered view and select from it. For example (not sure about the syntax):

```
CREATE VIEW foobar AS
select * from t1 order by col1 ASC,col2 DESC;
```

But it's going to be slow(ish).